# custom uitableviewCell outlets return nil

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm building an app where I use custom tableView Cells and i'm not really sure, if I do it right:
I'm not really sure about the cellOwner for example...

And the basic problem is, that all outlets that I defined and hocked up in IB, are nil at runtime.
Here is what I did:

- build a custom subclass of UITableViewCell (ProductListTableViewCell)
- made a nib, containing a UITableViewCell as root element
- set both the className and the owners Type of the cell to ProductListTableViewCell
- set the reuse identifier
- then put a couple of Labels etc onto the cell and generated the outlets via drag and drop
- double checked that all outlets are hocked up correctly.

The outlets however are all nil.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ProductListTableViewCell";

ProductListTableViewCell *cell =(ProductListTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    ProductListTableViewCell *cellOwner = [[ProductListTableViewCell alloc]init];

    UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProductListTableViewCell" bundle:nil];

    cell =(ProductListTableViewCell*) [[nib instantiateWithOwner:cellOwner options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

}
// all outlets are nil here
```

Comment: Did you set the same identifier ProductListTableViewCell to your table view xib ?

Comment: yes - same identifier set via IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductListTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductListTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = ProductListTableViewCell;
    self.ProductListTableViewCell=nil;

}
```

Comment: ok. I tried to load it via NSBundle - but that fails, since i pass in nil as owner...

Comment: setting the owner to another instance of the custom table cell has the same effect than doing it via UINib - all Outlets are nil.

Comment: ok - I  could not figure it out so I went with `cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCellBackgroundView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];` and since I could not get a reference to the outlets I configured them via `[((UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:100]) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape~ipad"] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;`